# Scrollbar is not being hidden

Tags: c, winapi

The [Scrollbar documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The system hides and disables a standard scroll bar when equal minimum
>   and maximum values are specified. **The system also hides and disables
>   a standard scroll bar if you specify a page size that includes the
>   entire scroll range of the scroll bar**.

I have set the page size to the scroll range value:

```
HWND hScroll = CreateWindowEx(0, "SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| SBS_HORZ, 10, 10, 400, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

SCROLLINFO scrollInfo;
scrollInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
scrollInfo.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_RANGE;
scrollInfo.nMin = 0;
scrollInfo.nMax = 639;
scrollInfo.nPage = 640;
scrollInfo.nPos = 0;
SetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_CTL, &scrollInfo, TRUE);
```

But the Scrollbar is not being hidden!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the right behaviour.
you missed the "standard" keyword here.

> A standard scroll bar is located in the nonclient area of a window. It is created with the window and displayed when the window is displayed. The sole purpose of a standard scroll bar is to enable the user to generate scrolling requests for viewing the entire content of the client area. You can include a standard scroll bar in a window by specifying WS_HSCROLL, WS_VSCROLL, or both styles when you create the window.

this is opposed to "control scroll bar":

> A scroll bar control is a control window that belongs to the SCROLLBAR window class.

the thing you created here is not standard scroll bar, it's control type created by `CreateWindow(Ex)`. meaning windows won't hide it. if you had created it with specifing `WS_HSCROLL, WS_VSCROLL` styles in the parent window creation - then yes, windows will hide it automatically for you.

if you think about it, it makes perfect API sense (from windows side). if yo uspecify `WS_?SCROLL` you're basically say "I think this window might be too small for its content, Windows, please show a scroll bar automatically if the contnet is to large and hide it's not relevant anymore" . if you create a scroll bar with `CreateWindow(Ex)` you're basically saying "No, I WANT this scroll bar to exist and be shown".